# Send data between to activities

Tags: fragment, send

Now i have created a new app with registration and logging in but the issue is how to set the email address id in the app i mean like when you go to settings to see which email is logged in right now like this pic [image]

Comment: What are you talking about ? where is your code ? what did you do so far ?

Comment: Take a look at this video i want to do this but with the email not the user name https://youtu.be/RyPuazLXQa4